# Bitwise Hacking Technique to Store Key and Value pair

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

If i want to store a `(Value, key) pair in priority list` i came across this bitwise hack
**Code:**

```
q.add(((long) value << 32) + index);
```

To get back the values:

```
  long cur = q.remove();
  int get_back_index = (int) cur;
  int get_back_value = cur>>>32;
```

I could not understand how this is happening please explain the logic behind this.

Answer (score 3):

It shifts the bits of 'value' to the left, and adds the bits of 'index'.

For instance, if you would look at them as decimal numbers, you could for instance multiply a value by 10000 to 'shift' it 4 digits to the left (basically right-pad it with 4 zeroes.

So a 'value' of 123 and an index of 456 could be combined into the number 1230456 using the formula 123 * 10000 + 456. To extract the numbers, you take the right part (0456) for the index, and divide the number by 10000 to get back the value.

This code does more or less the same, only for 32 binary digits instead of 4 decimal digits. `<<` is shifting left, `>>` is shifting right. Shifting left 32 bits is comparable to multiplying by 2^32, and shifting right is dividing.

Casting to int is basically truncating the value. The combined value is 64 bits, and an int is 32 bits, so by casting it to an integer, you discard half of the 64 bit value.